# How to handle change event for jPrompt input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I need to capture change/blur event of Jprompt input control. How to capture the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#prompt_button').click(function(){
    $('#popup_prompt').on('blur keyup', function(){
        alert($(this).val())
    });
});
```

This should work.

Here `$('#prompt_button')` is the button which triggers the popup open

Comment: $('#popup_prompt').blur( function(){
                        console.log($(this).val());
                    });      this worked for me Thanks @Cerlin Boss